# How to filtering date with date format (dd.MM.yyyy) in grid infragistic jquery?

Tags: jquery, date, grid, filtering, infragistics

I have code in jquery :

the source I use json to get data.

this is the sample http://samples.infragistics.com/jquery/grid/advanced-filtering

```
               $("#tbl-visit-schedule").igGrid({
                   columns: [
            { headerText: "Date", key: "Date",dataType:"date",format:"dd.MM.yyyy" },
            { headerText: "Name", key: "Name", dataType: "string" },
            { headerText: "Siegle", key: "Siegle", dataType: "string" },
            { headerText: "Group", key: "Group", dataType: "string" },
            { headerText: "Status", key: "Status", dataType: "string" },         
            {headerText: "Action", key: "Action", dataType: "string" }
            ],
                   width: "550px",
                   height: "400px",
                   dataSource: jsonp,
                   features: [

             {
                 name: 'Filtering',
                 allowFiltering: true,                     
                 type: 'local' 

             }
        ]
               });
```

Comment: I want filter format date column change with 'dd.MM.yyyy' not 'MM/dd/yyyy'. [sory for bad english] :)

Answer (score 2):

The date formatting is in fact only for display purposes. The filtering is still the same regardless of the applied formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the localization of the controls.  Infragistics does provide a few locales by default and the Bulgarian one has a format similar to what you are looking for.  You can see more on localization in the [help](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/jQuery/2012.1/CLR4.0?page=Customizing_the_localization_of_NetAdvantage_for_jQuery_controls.html).